# Libreoffice Snap doesn't have Hebrew Locale

Tags: libreoffice, snap, locale, flatpak, hebrew

Installing latest candidate snap package of Libreoffice (latest/candidate 7.2.4.1) within Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS doesn't show many languages, e.g. Hebrew

[image: snap 7.2.4.1 - no hebrew]
[image]

When installing the Flatpak version (7.2.4.1) or even the legacy Ubuntu-focal repo version (1:6.4.7-0ubuntu0.20.04.2) Hebrew locale is supported and shown.

[image: Flatpak latest shows Hebrew locale]

Please add Hebrew locale to the snap versions.

All the best

Uri

Comment: bug reported here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libreoffice/+bug/1955327

Answer (score 2):

Then remove this buggy snap by

```
sudo snap remove libreoffice --purge
```

and then install [LibreOffice from official PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Elibreoffice/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) using deb-packages:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:libreoffice/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libreoffice libreoffice-l10n-he
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but this is not the point. I know how to install a PPA and a deb package for that matter. I just think this issue should be fixed software-wise. Also, as I clearly wrote - Flatpak app has all locales, including Hebrew. All the best